# Chrome Extension's content script is bound to only a local web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've connected locally run page with "contentScript.js" as below.

#### manifest.json

```
  {
    "name": "Erase",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html" 

    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1:5000/"],
          "js": ["/contentScript.js"]
      }
  ],
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

#### contentScript.js

```
alert("this is naver")
```

So when I access http://127.0.0.1:5000/, the alert shows up. To do the same with [this site](http://naver.com/), I edited the `matches` to (only) include my target url "https://www.naver.com/" Actually I've tried many other urls until I find out that even `http://*/*` doesn't work. It seems like, I can't bind contentScript.js for non-local web file. What am I missing? There was a few examples where `permissions` had urls and I've tried that to no result.

Comment: 1) Add `*` at the end like `https://www.naver.com/*`, 2) `http` won't match `https` so you may want `<all_urls>` or `*://*/*`

Comment: @wOxxOm I didn't even catch it was `http`. The `https://www.naver.com/*` worked like charm. Thank you.